# has_one on a belongs_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am building a rails site and am having trouble with the associations. Basically I have the following:

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_one    :site, :through => :category
  named_scope :on_site,        lambda {|s| {:include => [:site], :conditions => ['sites.slug != ?', 's']}}
end
class Category
  belongs_to :site
  has_many   :publications
end
class Site
  has_many :categories
  has_many :publications, :through => :categories, :foreign_key => 'category_id'
end
```

`Publication.first.site` produces the first publication's site, `site.first.publications` does as well.

The trouble is with the `on_site` named scope, which produces the following error with something like `Publication.on_site('s')`

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'categories.category_id' in 'on clause': SELECT 
`publications`.`id` AS t0_r0, `publications`.`shoot_id` AS t0_r1, 
`publications`.`category_id` AS t0_r2, `publications`.`title` AS t0_r3, 
`publications`.`slug` AS t0_r4, `publications`.`publish_on` AS t0_r5, 
`publications`.`created_at` AS t0_r6, `publications`.`updated_at` AS t0_r7, 
`publications`.`description` AS t0_r8, `publications`.`media_base_path` AS t0_r9, 
`sites`.`id` AS t1_r0, `sites`.`name` AS t1_r1, `sites`.`created_at` AS t1_r2, 
`sites`.`updated_at` AS t1_r3, `sites`.`slug` AS t1_r4, `sites`.`description` AS t1_r5, 
`sites`.`dhd_merch_id` AS t1_r6, `sites`.`members_area_url` AS t1_r7 FROM `publications`
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` ON (`publications`.`id` = `categories`.`category_id`)  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `sites` ON (`sites`.`id` = `categories`.`site_id`) WHERE (sites.slug != 's')
```

I need that join to be publications.category_id = categories.id, any idea on what I've got wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is a problem with your current implementation:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` ON (`publications`.`id` = `categories`.`category_id`)
```

That SQL snippet is created by this association definition in `Site`:

```
has_many :publications, :through => :categories, :foreign_key => 'category_id'
```

The `foreign_key` there is not correct. Rails is looking for a column in `categories` called `category_id`, and expects the value of that column to match some publication id. But there is no correct `foreign_key` option that you can set, because the `categories` table looks like it does not have references to the `publications` table - it is the other way around.

I'm not sure it is possible to make ActiveRecord's `has_many :through` association work through an intermediate `has_many` association. But I think that you can use the nested association feature to make this work:

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  #has_one    :site, :through => :category
  named_scope :on_site,        lambda {|s| {:include => { :category => :site }, :conditions =>  ['sites.slug != ?', s]}}
end
```

Another issue is that you put `s` in quotes in the conditions array. It should not be in quotes.

Comment: Jesse, I'll give that a shot on monday, I'm pretty sure I tried all that stuff before I resorted to doing a join and it didn't work however (I'm pretty sure what you posted was my first implementation, before I just started doing all kinds of other stuff).

As for the s in quotes I don't think that really was the crux of it. If you look at the generated SQL I pasted the join is trying to match publication.id with category.category_id. When in fact it needs to be publication.category_id with category.id.

Comment: Oh yes, the quoted `s` is a completely separate issue. I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: Well, it looks like the code you posted doesn't fix it, I still need to do the joins manually. Your named_scope produces the same error, it tries to look for a column `sites_publications_join.category_id` which doesn't exist

Comment: Did you try removing the `has_many :publications...` line from Site? That might be confusing things.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution using the `:joins` option for the scope, if anyone's interested. I'd still like to know if it's possible without using `:joins` however.

```
  named_scope :on_site,        lambda {|s| {:joins =>
   ['LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` ON  (`publications`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`) ',
   'LEFT OUTER JOIN `sites`      ON  (`sites`.`id` = `categories`.`site_id`)'],
   :conditions => ['sites.slug = ?', s]}}
```

Comment: I hope you can comment on Jesse's reply, because it seems valid.